How can I verify integrity of the document types?
Are there any utilities to verify integrity of common document types used in the office environment (docx, pptx, xlsx, pdf, common image, audio and video files) without using the actual applications?
Contents of some documents of ours proved to be damaged due to storage issues. So, I need to sweep across the whole filesystem to verify all the files and report which of them are actually impacted.
The damaged content can be anywhere in the file, so just verifying file headers - like the file command does - or checking the file properties (length, dates), etc., won't be good enough. I need a tool which would open the files, verify integrity of their internal structures, and report the result either on stdout or through an exit code.
A solution which would do all the job and provide a final report would do as well, of course, if it already exists - it would save me a lot of scripting work. ;-)
I assume random technical issues, not a deliberate tampering - so I do not need to verify the actual contents of the documents. What I need is to identify the files which would probably fail to open in their respective apps.
Looking forward to receiving your suggestions.

Depending on exactly what happened, your filesystem may also have suffered metadata corruption, which could result in a variety of anomalies depending on how it is implemented. If it is a reasonably modern filesystem and it mounted successfully, then probably whatever corruption it did suffer has already been "cleaned up," but possibly not in a way that maximizes the odds of successful data recovery (for example, it may have removed dangling inodes).

If you want to verify integrity, then why not just save a SHA-256 sum alongside each document when you create it?

@TobySpeight, because you can't do that retroactively.

Many current file formats, such as documents created with Microsoft Office or LibreOffice, are renamed ZIP archives; these include some integrity information, so checking that should reveal random corruption. unzip -t will check the local CRCs stored in each file (see Test integrity of ZIP file? for details).
Verification tools exist for some other formats; I’m aware off-hand of jpeginfo which checks the integrity of JPEG/JFIF files.

Thank you, @Stephen.
I was considering verifying also the XML files inside, but indeed, if we assume technical issues only - as opposed to tampering - checking just the ZIP envelope should be enough.

regarding verifying XML files inside, note that the MS .xlsx etc files all use MS namespaces that will throw off a casual use of xmllint's (and xmlstarlet) ability to validate as a well formed document. It may be possible to make it work, but I recall spending multiple hours trying to solve that without success. Thinking back on it, maybe there is something in VBscript (etc) that would help with that OR just being able to open the file in the associated app would help, but how to automate?
